# How can I take the last row of every distinct ID that only has the status 'Placed' on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to get the last row of every order for which the last status is Placed on Mysql.

The data looks like this:

| orderid | clientid | timestamps | order_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 885 | 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | Placed |
| 1234 | 885 | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | Placed |
| 1234 | 885 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | Processed |
| 1235 | 885 | 2022-01-02 09:00:00 | Processed |
| 1235 | 885 | 2022-01-01 14:00:00 | Placed |
| 1236 | 886 | 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | Placed |
| 1236 | 886 | 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | Processed |

and here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE timestamps = (SELECT MAX(timestamps 
                    FROM orders 
                    GROUP BY orderid) and order_status = 'Placed'
```

But since for a same timestamp it could be both placed and processed like the order id 1236 I want to exclude this row completly since I only want the one that are just placed not processed. I tried to add row numbers but it didn't really helped me. Anyone has an idea or a hint on how to solve that? Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you share the sample output relative to the provided input? @Tmh

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily solved using [row_number()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

- Find the last record per **orderid**. Give precedence to **Processed** over **Placed** (by using descending alphabet sorting).
- Take only last records where **order_status** is **Placed**

---

```
select *

from  (select row_number() over (partition by orderid 
                                 order by timestamps desc, order_status desc) rn
              ,o.*
       from orders o 
       ) o
       
where  rn = 1 and order_status = 'Placed'
```

| rn | orderid | clientid | timestamps | order_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1e57b2afc49930ddf1e3efadfe5286f&hide=1)

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For version below < 8.0

```
select * from 
(select orderid,clientid,max(timestamps) timestamps,order_status
from orders
where order_status='Placed'
group by orderid,clientid,order_status) t
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iyHHdXgVw5UW6fVXePPaAM/1).

Exclude orders with same date that were placed and not processed -

```
select orderid,clientid,max(timestamps) timestamps,order_status from orders o1
where
not exists
(select 1 from orders o2
where o2.orderid = o1.orderid
and o2.timestamps = o1.timestamps
and o2.order_status <> o1.order_status)
and order_status<>'Processed'
group by orderid,clientid,order_status
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uJT9h2ZWFypUqV8jisPjJn/0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but then it's taking the orderid 1236 and I only want the orders that were placed and not processed ...

Comment: Added query for that.